# mysql error when using temporary table - "Can't reopen table: 'temporary_name"

Tags: python, mysql

i am using python to call a stored procedure which creates a temporary table

i am then trying to select from that table but am getting the error

```
Caught an exception while rendering: (1137, "Can't reopen table: 'temporary_name'")
```

can anyone see where i am going wrong

my code is

```
# create a cursor  
cur = connection.cursor()  
# execute the stored procedure   
cur.callproc('nodetree')  

# Get results from stored procedure
sql = "SELECT * FROM temporary_name"

cur.execute(sql)
```

the table is not called temporary_name i just put it in for example

Comment: Please give us code of procedure.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77169818/148271

Answer (score 1):

From [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/temporary-table-problems.html) (see bold text):

> You cannot refer to a TEMPORARY table more than once in the same query. For example, the following does not work:
>
> ```
> mysql> SELECT * FROM temp_table, temp_table AS t2;
> ERROR 1137: Can't reopen table: 'temp_table'
> ```
>
> This error also occurs **if you refer to a temporary table multiple times in a stored function under different aliases**, even if the references occur in different statements within the function.

Comment: i don't have any aliases in my stored procedure

Comment: @John are you able to execute the stored procedure and the select query from command line client? Where is you exception thrown: `callproc()` or `execute()`?

Answer (score -1):

You can use usual table and than drop it.