# MYSQL Error updating record: Can't reopen table (Temporary table)

Tags: php, mysql, temp-tables

Before I get to my question I want you to know that I started learning MYSQL and PHP last week so it could be some of the worst coding you've seen in a while.

Enough with the excuses, here's my problem, while Executing the following PHP script:

```
           if($hdd!==0){
                  $sql="CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE custom AS SELECT * from `builds`;";
                $conn->query($sql);
                 if($hdd==1){
                 $sql="UPDATE custom SET HDD = null;";
                $conn->query($sql);
            }

                $conn->query("DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS ROWPERROW2;");
$conn->query("CREATE PROCEDURE ROWPERROW2()
BEGIN
DECLARE n INT DEFAULT 0;

DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 1;
DECLARE price INT DEFAULT 0;

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM custom INTO n;
SET i=1;

SET price=0;
WHILE i<=n DO 
SET price = (SELECT sum(`lowestPrice`) FROM ((SELECT `lowestPrice` FROM products WHERE name IN (SELECT `Motherboard` from `custom` Where `id`=i )) UNION (SELECT `lowestPrice` FROM products WHERE name IN (SELECT `Cooling` from `custom` Where `id`=i )) UNION (SELECT `lowestPrice` FROM products WHERE name IN (SELECT `PC_Case` from `custom` Where `id`=i )) UNION (SELECT `lowestPrice` FROM products WHERE name IN (SELECT `PSU` from `custom` Where `id`=i )) UNION (SELECT `lowestPrice` FROM products WHERE name IN (SELECT `GPU` from `custom` Where `id`=i )) UNION (SELECT `lowestPrice` FROM products WHERE name IN (SELECT `Memory` from `custom` Where `id`=i )) UNION (SELECT `lowestPrice` FROM products WHERE name IN (SELECT `SSD` from `custom` Where `id`=i )) UNION (SELECT `lowestPrice` FROM products WHERE name IN (SELECT `HDD` from `custom` Where `id`=i )) UNION (SELECT `lowestPrice` FROM products WHERE name IN (SELECT `CPU` from `custom` Where `id`=i ))) as A);
UPDATE custom SET `TotalPrice`=price WHERE `id`=i;
SET i = i + 1;
END WHILE;
End;");
                if ($conn->query("CALL ROWPERROW2();") === TRUE) {
    echo "Builds Record updated successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error updating record: " . $conn->error;
}
            }
```

I get the following error:

> Error updating record: Can't reopen table: 'custom'

"custom" is a temporary table, so I guess that's what causing the problem, how can I work my way around it? I can't just create a normal table each time because I want it to work on a multi-user environment

Comment: temporary tables are session/connection bounded meaning the PHP MySQL client which made the temporary table can only acces it.. So you need to include the creating of the temporary table within this code before you create the SP ROWPERROW2

Comment: The creating of the temporary table is indeed included in the code, I just dropped the lines of code where it's created, I updated the post so you can see.

Answer (score 0):

Found a work around, it's not pretty, but it works.
What I did was creating multiple temporary tables based on the original temp table ('contents'), and then used them in the procedure so each table is used only once, like so:

```
                 $conn->query(" CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE t1 AS SELECT * FROM custom;");
                 $conn->query(" CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE t2 AS SELECT * FROM custom;");
                $conn->query(" CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE t3 AS SELECT * FROM custom;");
                $conn->query(" CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE t4 AS SELECT * FROM custom;");
                $conn->query(" CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE t5 AS SELECT * FROM custom;");
                $conn->query(" CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE t6 AS SELECT * FROM custom;");
                $conn->query(" CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE t7 AS SELECT * FROM custom;");
                $conn->query(" CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE t8 AS SELECT * FROM custom;");
                $conn->query(" CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE t9 AS SELECT * FROM custom;");
```

And changed the procedure so it'd use each table only once:

```
$conn->query("CREATE PROCEDURE ROWPERROW2()
BEGIN
DECLARE n INT DEFAULT 0;

DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 1;
DECLARE price INT DEFAULT 0;

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM builds INTO n;
SET i=1;

SET price=0;
WHILE i<=n DO 
SET price = (SELECT sum(`lowestPrice`) FROM ((SELECT `lowestPrice` FROM products WHERE name IN (SELECT `Motherboard` from `t1` Where `id`=i )) UNION (SELECT `lowestPrice` FROM products WHERE name IN (SELECT `Cooling` from `t2` Where `id`=i )) UNION (SELECT `lowestPrice` FROM products WHERE name IN (SELECT `PC_Case` from `t3` Where `id`=i )) UNION (SELECT `lowestPrice` FROM products WHERE name IN (SELECT `PSU` from `t4` Where `id`=i )) UNION (SELECT `lowestPrice` FROM products WHERE name IN (SELECT `GPU` from `t5` Where `id`=i )) UNION (SELECT `lowestPrice` FROM products WHERE name IN (SELECT `Memory` from `t6` Where `id`=i )) UNION (SELECT `lowestPrice` FROM products WHERE name IN (SELECT `SSD` from `t7` Where `id`=i )) UNION (SELECT `lowestPrice` FROM products WHERE name IN (SELECT `HDD` from `t8` Where `id`=i )) UNION (SELECT `lowestPrice` FROM products WHERE name IN (SELECT `CPU` from `t9` Where `id`=i ))) as A);
UPDATE custom SET `TotalPrice`=price WHERE `id`=i;
SET i = i + 1;
END WHILE;
End;");
                if ($conn->query("CALL ROWPERROW2();") === TRUE) {
    echo "Builds Record updated successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error updating record: " . $conn->error;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was getting similar error. I realized that temporary table doesn't support even concurrent read, let alone write. Just ensure one read at a time and it should work fine. In my case I had used it in common table expression (CTE). I took it out of CTE and it worked fine even when I used it in statements one after other.

This is a limitation of Temporary tables which is mentioned documentation ([as per this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6953597/148271))